# SQL Order by the sum of aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, alias

To preface, this is Microsoft SQL Server.  I have several different columns of various earnings from different years.  I need to order by the total sales of each given product, but not report it as an actual column.  The commented line is how I tried to do it, but it seems you can't order by an alias.  How would one go about this?

```
SELECT 
    StockItems.StockItemID, 
    StockItemName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2013-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2014-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2013,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2014,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2015,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2015-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2016-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2016
FROM 
    Warehouse.StockItems

    INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines
        ON Warehouse.StockItems.StockItemID = Sales.OrderLines.StockItemID
    INNER JOIN Sales.Orders
        ON Sales.OrderLines.OrderID = Sales.Orders.OrderID

GROUP BY 
    StockItems.StockItemID, 
    StockItemName

--ORDER BY SUM(Sales2013 + Sales2014 + Sales2015 + Sales2016)
```

Comment: You no longer need the case expressions at the order by, so you don't need the column alisases; try *ORDER BY SUM(Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice)*

Answer (score 2):

Two methods

1. Put your query as inner query and order on it
2. put the full formula in order by

query for #1

```
select * from 
    (
    SELECT 
        StockItems.StockItemID, 
        StockItemName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2013-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2014-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2013,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2014,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2015,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2015-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2016-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2016
    FROM 
        Warehouse.StockItems

        INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines
            ON Warehouse.StockItems.StockItemID = Sales.OrderLines.StockItemID
        INNER JOIN Sales.Orders
            ON Sales.OrderLines.OrderID = Sales.Orders.OrderID

    GROUP BY 
        StockItems.StockItemID, 
        StockItemName
    ) temp
order by SUM(Sales2013 + Sales2014 + Sales2015 + Sales2016)
```

query for #2

```
 SELECT 
        StockItems.StockItemID, 
        StockItemName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2013-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2014-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2013,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2014,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2015,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2015-01-01'
            AND OrderDate < '2016-01-01'
            THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2016
    FROM 
        Warehouse.StockItems

        INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines
            ON Warehouse.StockItems.StockItemID = Sales.OrderLines.StockItemID
        INNER JOIN Sales.Orders
            ON Sales.OrderLines.OrderID = Sales.Orders.OrderID

    GROUP BY 
        StockItems.StockItemID, 
        StockItemName

order by SUM(Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT StockItemID
    , StockItemName
    , Sales2013
    , Sales2014
    , Sales2015
    , Sales2016
    , Sales2013 + Sales2014 + Sales2015 + Sales2016 total_sales
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        StockItems.StockItemID, 
        StockItemName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2013-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2014-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2013,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2014,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2014-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2015-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2015,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2015-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2016-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales2016
    FROM 
        Warehouse.StockItems

        INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines
        ON Warehouse.StockItems.StockItemID = Sales.OrderLines.StockItemID
        INNER JOIN Sales.Orders
        ON Sales.OrderLines.OrderID = Sales.Orders.OrderID

    GROUP BY 
        StockItems.StockItemID, 
        StockItemName
)
ORDER BY total_sales
```

Answer (score 1):

Add SUM column:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2013-01-01'
        AND OrderDate < '2016-01-01'
        THEN Quantity * OrderLines.UnitPrice END) AS Sales_SUM
```

Then order by Sales_SUM

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best performing solution would require to use a PIVOT, I wrap it in a CTE for better readability:

```
;WITH pvt AS (
    SELECT 
        StockItems.StockItemID, 
        StockItemName,
        YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
        Quantity * OrderLines AS SalesTotal,
        SUM(Quantity * OrderLines) OVER (PARTITION BY StockItems.StockItemID) AS SalesForStockItemForYear 
    FROM 
        Warehouse.StockItems
        INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines
            ON Warehouse.StockItems.StockItemID = Sales.OrderLines.StockItemID
        INNER JOIN Sales.Orders
            ON Sales.OrderLines.OrderID = Sales.Orders.OrderID
    WHERE
        YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2013,2014,2015,2016)
    PIVOT (
        SUM(SalesTotal) FOR OrderYear IN ([2013],[2014],[2015],[2016])
    )
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    pvt.StockItemID,
    pvt.StockItemName,
    pvt.[2013] as Sales2013,
    pvt.[2014] as Sales2014,
    pvt.[2015] as Sales2015,
    pvt.[2016] as Sales2016
FROM
    pvt
ORDER BY
    pvt.SalesForStockItemForYear DESC
```